# Infinite loop in connection:didReceiveData in AFURLConnectionOperation.m

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking2 for my iOS project which requires extensive image loading.

After downloading a certain number of images, all outgoing requests are queued in the operation queue and never go out.

I found out that is because in

> AFURLConnectionOperation.m,(void)connection:didReceiveData

there is a while(YES) loop and it only breaks when

> [self.outputStream hasSpaceAvailable]

or when

> self.outputStream.streamError

occurs.

But, in my case, the [self.outputStream hasSpaceAvailable] returns NO, and the operation remains stuck in the while (YES) loop.

Has anyone  experienced the issue, and what is the solution?

Here is the code of

> AFURLConnectionOperation.m,(void)connection:didReceiveData

for context:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection __unused *)connection
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSUInteger length = [data length];
    while (YES) { 
        ...
        if ([self.outputStream hasSpaceAvailable]) {
            ...
            break;
        }
        if (self.outputStream.streamError) {
            ....
            return;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Note: I am currently overriding that function with the code below to overcome the issue.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection __unused *)connection
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSUInteger length = [data length];
    if ([self.outputStream hasSpaceAvailable]) {
        const uint8_t *dataBuffer = (uint8_t *) [data bytes];
        [self.outputStream write:&dataBuffer[0] maxLength:length];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `self.outputStream` is this something in your app?  If so then it looks like you aren't processing that stream, leading to the deadlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a bug in AFNetworking. see [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2496).

There is a committed fix [mentioned](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/106143e5fc40c4e7c5684207086566dc6482c5f6) in this issue, but it doesn't seem to be available in the latest version for some reason (2.5.4).

Comment: True. Just for recommendation, I can also offer @cmh using  cocoapods, by that way he wouldn't encounter with this issue.